# Issues with Nodemcu, LoRa Module (Lora-02), and Bluetooth Module (Hc-05) for SMS Communication

Tags: arduino, esp8266, bluetooth, nodemcu, lora

I am currently working on a project that involves using an node mcu, a LoRa module (Lora-02), and a Bluetooth module (HC-05) to enable the transmission of free SMS between two mobile devices when there is no network coverage.

Here's a brief overview of the flow:

1. A mobile device connects to the nodemcu via Bluetooth.
2. The mobile device sends data to the Bluetooth module.
3. The Bluetooth module forwards the data to the LoRa module (Lora-02).
4. The LoRa module transmits the data to another LoRa module.
5. The receiving LoRa module forwards the data to another Bluetooth
   module.
6. The second Bluetooth module connects to a second mobile device.

The system is not working . I am facing challenges in pinpointing the issue, and I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions from the community to help me troubleshoot and resolve this problem.

the Bluetooth do connect with the mobile but I can't see data on the serail app I tried to print data on serial monitor but it is not visible on serial monitor too

The code for user 1

```
#include <SPI.h>              // include libraries
#include <LoRa.h>
#define SS 15
#define RST 16
#define DIO0 2

byte msgCount = 0;            // count of outgoing messages
byte localAddress = 0xBB;     // address of this device
byte destination = 0xFF;      // destination to send to

int buzzer=3;

String outgoing;              // outgoing message
String Mymessage;             // stores message from the bluetooth

int calling; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                   // initialize serial
  Serial.println("LoRa Duplex");
  LoRa.setPins(SS, RST, DIO0);

  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {             // initialize ratio at 915 MHz
    Serial.println("LoRa init failed. Check your connections.");
    while (true);                       // if failed, do nothing
  }

  Serial.println("LoRa init succeeded.");
  pinMode(buzzer,OUTPUT);
  }

   
 void loop() {

   if(Serial.available()>0)
   {
       //read data
       Mymessage=Serial.readString();
       sendMessage(Mymessage);
       delay(100);
       Mymessage = "";
   }


    // parse for a packet, and call onReceive with the result:
    onReceive(LoRa.parsePacket());
   }

   void sendMessage(String outgoing) {
      LoRa.beginPacket();                   // start packet
      LoRa.write(destination);              // add destination address
      LoRa.write(localAddress);             // add sender address
      LoRa.write(msgCount);                 // add message ID
      LoRa.write(outgoing.length());        // add payload length
      LoRa.print(outgoing);                 // add payload
      LoRa.endPacket();                     // finish packet and send it
      msgCount++;                           // increment message ID
     }

     void onReceive(int packetSize) {
        if (packetSize == 0) return;          // if there's no packet, return

            // read packet header bytes:
            int recipient = LoRa.read();          // recipient address
            byte sender = LoRa.read();            // sender address
            byte incomingMsgId = LoRa.read();     // incoming msg ID
            byte incomingLength = LoRa.read();    // incoming msg length

            String incoming = "";

            while (LoRa.available()) {
            incoming += (char)LoRa.read();
            }

            if (incomingLength != incoming.length()) {   // check length for error
                 //Serial.println("error: message length does not match length");
                 ;
                 return;                             // skip rest of function
              }

          // if the recipient isn't this device or broadcast,
          if (recipient != localAddress && recipient != 0xFF) {
                 // Serial.println("This message is not for me.");
                    ;
               return;                             // skip rest of function
           }

           // if message is for this device, or broadcast, print details:
       
           String q = getValue(incoming, ',', 0);
          // Serial.println("q: " + q);

          calling = q.toInt();
        //Serial.println(q);
        if(calling== 45)
        {
              digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
              delay(1000);

              calling = 0;  
 
              }

              else 
              Serial.println(q);
               }
      String getValue(String data, char separator, int index)
       {
         int found = 0;
         int strIndex[] = { 0, -1 };
         int maxIndex = data.length() - 1;

         for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex && found <= index; i++) {
             if (data.charAt(i) == separator || i == maxIndex) {
                 found++;
                 strIndex[0] = strIndex[1] + 1;
                 strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
                }
          }
          return found > index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
  }
```

code for user-2

```
#include <SPI.h>              // include libraries
#include <LoRa.h>
#define SS 15
#define RST 16
#define DIO0 2

byte msgCount = 0;            // count of outgoing messages
byte localAddress = 0xFF;     // address of this device
byte destination = 0xBB;      // destination to send to

int buzzer=3;

String outgoing;              // outgoing message
String Mymessage;             // stores message from the bluetooth

int calling; 

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                   // initialize serial
  Serial.println("LoRa Duplex");
  LoRa.setPins(SS, RST, DIO0);

  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {             // initialize ratio at 915 MHz
    Serial.println("LoRa init failed. Check your connections.");
    while (true);                       // if failed, do nothing
  }

  Serial.println("LoRa init succeeded.");
  pinMode(buzzer,OUTPUT);
  }

   
 void loop() {

   if(Serial.available()>0)
   {
       //read data
       Mymessage=Serial.readString();
       sendMessage(Mymessage);
       delay(100);
       Mymessage = "";
   }


    // parse for a packet, and call onReceive with the result:
    onReceive(LoRa.parsePacket());
   }

   void sendMessage(String outgoing) {
      LoRa.beginPacket();                   // start packet
      LoRa.write(destination);              // add destination address
      LoRa.write(localAddress);             // add sender address
      LoRa.write(msgCount);                 // add message ID
      LoRa.write(outgoing.length());        // add payload length
      LoRa.print(outgoing);                 // add payload
      LoRa.endPacket();                     // finish packet and send it
      msgCount++;                           // increment message ID
     }

     void onReceive(int packetSize) {
        if (packetSize == 0) return;          // if there's no packet, return

            // read packet header bytes:
            int recipient = LoRa.read();          // recipient address
            byte sender = LoRa.read();            // sender address
            byte incomingMsgId = LoRa.read();     // incoming msg ID
            byte incomingLength = LoRa.read();    // incoming msg length

            String incoming = "";

            while (LoRa.available()) {
            incoming += (char)LoRa.read();
            }

            if (incomingLength != incoming.length()) {   // check length for error
                 //Serial.println("error: message length does not match length");
                 ;
                 return;                             // skip rest of function
              }

          // if the recipient isn't this device or broadcast,
          if (recipient != localAddress && recipient != 0xFF) {
                 // Serial.println("This message is not for me.");
                    ;
               return;                             // skip rest of function
           }

           // if message is for this device, or broadcast, print details:
       
           String q = getValue(incoming, ',', 0);
          // Serial.println("q: " + q);

          calling = q.toInt();
        //Serial.println(q);
        if(calling== 45)
        {
              digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
              delay(1000);
              digitalWrite(buzzer,LOW);
              delay(1000);

              calling = 0;  
 
              }

              else 
              Serial.println(q);
               }
      String getValue(String data, char separator, int index)
       {
         int found = 0;
         int strIndex[] = { 0, -1 };
         int maxIndex = data.length() - 1;

         for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex && found <= index; i++) {
             if (data.charAt(i) == separator || i == maxIndex) {
                 found++;
                 strIndex[0] = strIndex[1] + 1;
                 strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
                }
          }
          return found > index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
  }
```

this is my circuit diagram

hs-05 bluetooth module is attach with rx and tx pin of nodemcu and vcc is attach to vin and ground is attach to gnd of nodemcu
[image]